# How to resolve the Microsoft.Azure.Workflows.WebJobs.Extensions error for the Aure Logic app

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to deploy an Azure standard Logic app with Private endpoints using Terraform. It creates the resources and successfully completed without an errors but it is displaying below error when trying to access the logic app from the portal and also workflow creation is also failing.

> Microsoft.Azure.Workflows.WebJobs.Extensions: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.IListenerDecorator' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.38.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: The error is more likely seems related to a compatibility issue. Have you checked the logic app runtime version with the web jobs extensions version compatibility? @Swabha

Comment: I am new to the Terraform and logic app, I have deployed the logic app using terraform code, how to check the version compatability @Jahnavi

Comment: You are looking for this same [MSDoc](https://github.com/VeeraMS/LogicApp-deployment-with-Secure-Storage#deploy-logic-app-with-secured-storage-account-having-private-endpoints) deployment right? Correct me if my understanding on your requirement is not accurate. @Swabha

Comment: Yeah @Jahnavi, exact same document but using Terraform code.

Comment: Updated below with terraform. @Swabha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Use below modified terraform code for deploying a standard Logic app with Private endpoints.*

```bash
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example"{
name = "caroline"
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "jahnetwork"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  dns_servers         = ["10.0.0.4", "10.0.0.5"]

  subnet {
    name           = "subnet1"
    address_prefix = "10.0.1.0/24"
  }
  }
  
resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "servicejah"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  delegation {
    name = "delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
    }
  }
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "service" {
  name                 = "servicejah"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]

  enforce_private_link_service_network_policies = true
}

data "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "strplatlasta"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
  name                 = "newstshj"
  storage_account_name = data.azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  quota                = 50
  depends_on = [
    data.azurerm_storage_account.example
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "mydomain.com"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "example" {
  name                  = "testjah"
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "endpoint" {
  name                = "jahpe"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.service.id
  tags                = {}
  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "newjpsc"
    is_manual_connection           = false
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_logic_app_standard.logic_app.id
    subresource_names              = ["sites"]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "azurelogicervice-plan"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  kind                = "elastic"


  sku {
    tier = "WorkflowStandard"
    size = "WS1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_standard" "logic_app" {
  name                       = "mylatestjap"
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = data.azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = data.azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  https_only                 = true
  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET"      = "1"
    "WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL"       = "1"
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME"     = "node"
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" = "~14"
  }
  site_config {
    use_32_bit_worker_process        = true
    ftps_state                       = "Disabled"
    websockets_enabled               = false
    min_tls_version                  = "1.2"
    runtime_scale_monitoring_enabled = false
    vnet_route_all_enabled           = true
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_share.example
  ]
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Runtime version is showing as blank --- in the logic app, how to fix this issue. Have made the version to use ~4 in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I got it resolved after updating the LogicApp (Standard) Configuration setting "**AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensionBundle__version**"

from default versions range

```
[1.*, 2.0.0)
```

to specific version

```
[1.31.12]
```

For future deployments to prevent overwriting the changes in app, [Extension bundles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#extension-bundles) file shall be updated in the project/template code base.

Some more details about upgrading the LogicApp to use Functions version 4 shall be referred here [Azure Logic Apps Standard now supports Azure Functions v4](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/azure-logic-apps-standard-now-supports-azure-functions-v4/ba-p/3656072)